How to prevent Pylance and pylint in vscode from analyzing python files not in current workspace?
I have a python project. When I want to reuse some old code, I drag and drop files from other folders into vscode. but the moment those files open, I am getting hundreds of errors saying all sorts of errors. I want pylint and pylance to analyze the files only in the workspace.
How can I do that?
I tried adding these in settings.json as said by chatgpt and other docs
settings.json present in .vscode folder
    "python.languageServer": "Pylance",
    "python.analysis.diagnosticMode": "workspace",
    "python.analysis.include": [
        "${workspaceFolder}"
    ],
    "pylint.cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",

    "pylint.args": [
        "--rcfile=${workspaceFolder}\\pyproject.toml"
    ]

pyproject.toml
[tool.pylint.'MASTER']
init-hook = '''
import sys
from pathlib import Path

workspace_folder = Path(__file__).parent
sys.path.insert(0, str(workspace_folder))
'''

still when I open some files from another folder, I get lots of errors
Versions
python : 3.9.13
Vscode : 1.89.1
Pylance extension : 2024.5.1
Pylint : 3.2.2

Could you show us some screenshots?

i keep the workspaces seperate by opening a new instant of VS code. it is much easier than messing with th JSON file...

Aside from that, it proides an opportunity to clean the errors :)

You could create a pyrightconfig.json file in your workspace root:
{
    "include": ["**/*.py"],
    "exclude": ["**/site-packages/**", "**/distutils/**", "**/node_modules/**", "**/__pycache__/**"]
}

